# Error in comparing hashes due to encoding

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert a php application into a python one and I am stuck on the hashes

Using MySQL and SQLAlchemy has the ORM

MySQL

```
field : client_hash
type : varchar(20)
collation: Latin1_bin
```

SQLAlchemy

```
client_hash = Column(Unicode)
```

I have tried other types like varchar but it seems to give me hashes that are further away form what I am looking for.

When I view the has in phpmyadmin it looks like

```
ù3×þØc(    7JûìÎËþf–E”
```

I get this hash from the client

```
\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\x96E\x94
```

and there server is excepting this as the correct answer

```
\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\u2013E\u201d
```

I am not sure how to convert the last two into hex or if they are even the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two are *not* the same. The first hex sequence is a raw representation of a Python  byte string; it decodes from Latin-1 to:

```
>>> '\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\x96E\x94'.decode('latin1')
u'\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\x96E\x94'
>>> print '\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\x96E\x94'.decode('latin1')
ù3×þØc( 7JûìÎËþfE
```

but your second value is a *unicode* string; it uses the Python `\uxxxx` unicode codepoint escapes:

```
>>> u'\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\u2013E\u201d'
u'\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\u2013E\u201d'
>>> print u'\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\u2013E\u201d'
ù3×þØc( 7JûìÎËþf–E”
```

So the Unicode literal value does match what you see in phpmyadmin.

The are the same except for the last 3 characters:

```
>>> latin1 = '\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\x96E\x94'.decode('latin1')
>>> unicode_literal = u'\xf93\xd7\xfe\xd8c(\t\x9d7J\xfb\xec\xce\xcb\xfef\u2013E\u201d'
>>> latin1[:-3] == unicode_literal[:-3]
True
>>> latin1[-2] == unicode_literal[-2]
True
>>> latin1[-1] == unicode_literal[-1]
False
>>> latin1[-3] == unicode_literal[-3]
False
```

Without more information it is hard to tell why your MySQL setup is returning `\x96` and `\x94` instead of the `\u2013` and `\u201d` codepoints; I don't directly see the correlation there.

You'll probably need to configure the SQLAlchemy connector to match the encoding used in this MySQL database, setting the `charset` parameter at the database connection level, table level or even column level if need be.